# Pay through Paypal using a credit card

Tags: asp.net, razor, paypal, credit-card

I have a requirement of integrating paypal in one of my asp.net website.

But I need to have a facility that One could pay through Paypal by using a credit card even if they don't have a paypal account. For credit cards, I don't have any idea of how can it be done through paypal development portal.

So can anybody let me know how to go about this and any reference link where I can find some details for this.?

I think one of the option I should go with is: `PayPal Website Payments Pro` but I have no idea about that and Is it a free service or a paid one.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PayPal Payments Pro does allow you to process credit card transactions using the Direct Payment API's. That product is currently available to US, UK, and Canadian merchants. The REST credit card process mentioned is only for US merchants at the moment.

Payments Pro isn't free. There a $30 a month fee.

Payments Standard and Express Checkout are both free and don't require that your buyers have a PayPal account but they are required to redirect to the PayPal site to log into their account or enter their credit card information.

If you have a more specific question I can help you further.

Comment: Can you please provide me some tutorial by which I can integrate in my application..?

Comment: For which product? Standard, Express Checkout, Direct Payment or REST?

Comment: `Payments Standard and Express Checkout` which ever is more feasible for asp.net application..

Comment: The Merchant SDK - http://paypal.github.io/ - has a .NET example for all the classic PayPal API's which includes Express Checkout. 
Its hard to give a proper tutorial in a comment. If you want, you can create a ticket - https://www.paypal.com/dts - give me the ticket number and I can go into greater detail about everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can make credit card payments via the new [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/).  Depending on your use case check the documentation for sale (directly charging a card), or authorize and capture.  You also have the option of storing cards in the vault for later use.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether you have gone through the Paypal developer's FAQ. Please go through this link once- 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq

Ideally to integrate paypal to a development site, A business account needs to be created.So when the user clicks on the pay now button on your site you send that userId and password to Paypal webservice and authenticate yourself as business user. it redirects to teh paypal site after authentication. So even if the user  does not have an account with paypal they can pay using paypal(Which authenticates your site).

All the paypal integration is paid service.

Comment: Ok..But what about [Website Payments Standard](https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-standard-overview-outside). It has No monthly, set-up, or cancellation fees.

Comment: See the case where there is no monthly setup / cancellation fee, they charge per transaction ..something like 2.9%+$0.30 in US. Need to look into details of how it works in India.